# How to configure JAAS in JBoss AS 7 to accept only ONE SESSION PER USER?

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, jboss7.x, jaas

I recently got JBoss to work with JAAS authentication into my JSF application. Everything seemed to work fine when I realized I was capable of logging in with the same user in different computers/browsers.

I was wondering if there is any configuration I am missing to make it understand that I can't allow more than one session per user.

At first, I thought it would be pretty straightforward, though that's not what I realized later. Been reading for 2 days at the JBoss community website and in here.

Here is how my configuration in standalone.xml looks like:

```
<security-domain name="***Realm" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/***DS"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where email=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role_name, 'Roles' from users where email = ?"/>
                        <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                        <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

And the related JAAS tags into my web.xml:

```
<!-- Allowed Roles -->
<security-role>
    <role-name>SUPERADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
<!-- Protected Areas -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Only SUPER Admins</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/superadmin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>SUPERADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Only Admins and SuperAdmins</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>SUPERADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Users and admins and SuperAdmins</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/user/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>SUPERADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Validation By Form -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<!-- Filter to get the user name and work with it -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>br.com.icts.rybenapessoal.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I appreciate any help on either pointing me in the right direction or helping me find out more documentation around this issue.

Regards.
Arthur

Comment: Why would you like to restrict to just one session per user?

Comment: The request I got from my bosses is that the resource that the login system is supposed to protect is a payed content. So they do not want people to access protected resources simultaneously. And by the way, thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that will do what you want on the contaner managed auth level. You'll probably have to implement such restrictions yourself.

Comment: I am not aware of a configurable out-of-the box solution either. If you want to implement it, consider using a `javax.servlet.Filter` in combination with a cluster-wide state (a list containing the currently logged in users together with their session ID): So if there is a request with same user, but different session ID, reject it.

Comment: Beryllium I really appreciate your help. It seems what youre telling me can really work. I will give it a shot on implementing my own filter, because so far I have been using a basic filter for authentication.

Comment: Do you mean "basic authentication" or do you already have a filter which is used for authentication?

Comment: For future reference and other users that might bump into this post. This picketbox authentication in JBoss was completely replaced by project Elytron and solves this and other problems that were discussed here. Thanks.